# Minimum width Navigation controller in conjunction with a Split View Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a split view controller as created through the wizard. I changed the UITableViewController that's linked to the navigation controller to a UICollectionViewController.

That works fine that when I drag from the left to the right it appears and swipe to the right hides it.

But, what i'm trying to do is have the UICollectionViewController stay a minimum for 50 pixels in width, so it looks like a vertical navigation controller.

Does anyone know how I can specify that the NavigationController never lets the UICollectionViewController shrink to less than 50 pixels wide?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this with a UISplitViewController. You'll have to create your own splitView-like controller to do this.

Comment: What do you want to see when the app opens in portrait? Do you want to see this 50 point wide master view, or should you only see the detail view?

Comment: I read that it's a 320 pixel minimum and tested it out. I ended up using a view with a collection view.